# How to guess when a number is "far away" from expected value

Tags: dataset, prediction, outliers

I have a bunch of plots that look like the following:
[image]

Eyeballing this, it's clear that we have a bunch of values that follow a pattern which we can predict from a linear model, but then a couple that are "outliers". What are some accurate ways we can identify these outliers?

**My thoughts**

One way to go about this is to create a LM to fit this plot, and then look for points that are some threshold away from that LM. However, we see that there are a bunch of outliers that also follow a linear pattern; if there were enough of these, it could skew the LM so that it would be much more difficult to identify real outliers. Another idea is to assess the mean and SD of this dataset, and if a point is far enough away (determined by z-score) we say it's an outlier. Just a few thoughts; any ideas or thoughts would be helpful.

Comment: look up [cooks distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cook%27s_distance) and read about [leverage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leverage_(statistics)). When you plot a linear regression fit in R this is one of the standard plots that R produces. Other measures include [DFFITS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DFFITS) and [DFBETAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Influential_observation)

Comment: With data like this I would want to use quantile regression or some kind of robust regression. Then just look at the residuals.

Comment: @bdeonovic Leverage will not identify this kind of outlier.  Large residuals relative to a robust fit of some regression model (such as IRLS or even Loess) will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @whuber. What makes leverage not work in this scenario?

Comment: @bdeonovic Leverage measures how much a data point might be controlling a linear fit.  Data points with huge residuals but with average $x$ values will have no leverage at all.  A linear fit that has been "fooled" by clump of residuals also might not identify them as residuals in the first place, in which case they will not be found using most (perhaps all) usual OLS diagnostic measures.

Comment: So leverage might be able to identify some points with both extreme covariate and extreme response, but not necessarily extreme response and average covariate? Am I understanding correctly?

Answer (score 5):

**Use a robust non-parametric fit, such as Loess, to smooth the points.  A boxplot of the residuals will separately indicate all those that are "far outliers."**

The code below computes those far outliers using a standard (robust) method very similar to the one popularized by John Tukey.  Assuming the robust fit captures the main trend of the points, up to 25% of the data can be high outliers and another 25% low outliers and still be detected.  An advantage of Loess is that it can be "tuned" to local parts of the plot or to follow the global trend; so if it seems to be affected by clumps of outliers, make it smooth more agressively (by modifying the `f` parameter in this implementation).

[image: Figure]

The Loess fit is drawn as a black curve.  The automatically identified outliers have been overplotted in red.

How well does it work?  Let's make the random errors fifty times greater and try again:

[image: Figure 2]

That's about its limit: if we increase the random errors still further, the "noise" around the main body of points will grow to absorb the outliers one by one.  Experiment by changing the `sd` parameter in the calculation of `y`.

```R
#
# Generate sample data.
# Comment out `set.seed` to vary the data on subsequent runs.
#
set.seed(17)
x <- seq(250, 950, length.out=100)
y <- 120*(1 - exp((x-2000)/2000))
i <- runif(length(x)) < 1/8
y[i] <- y[i] + 20 * ceiling(rnorm(sum(i)))
y[!i] <- y[!i] + rnorm(sum(!i), sd=0.1)    # `sd=5` for the second figure
#
# Plot the data.
#
par(mfrow=c(1,1))
plot(x,y, ylim=c(0, max(y)), col="#404040", xlab="", ylab="")
#
# Fit the data with a robust method and plot the fit.
#
model <- lowess(y ~ x)
lines(model, lwd=2)
#
# Identify the extreme residuals and plot them.
#
residuals <- y - model$y
hinges <- quantile(residuals, c(1/4, 3/4))
step <- diff(hinges)
fences <- 2.5*step*c(-1,1) + hinges
far.out <- residuals < fences[1] | residuals > fences[2]
points(x[far.out], y[far.out], pch=19, col="Red")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is almost perfect! Do you have any suggestions for changing the "2.5" multiplier on the fences? It works in this case, but in other cases (I have a lot of these plots), 2.5x is too sensitive (i.e. the fences are farrr too small), and sometimes it's not sensitive enough. Can we replace it with some function so it's more robust?

Comment: It's already as robust as one could hope for.  Your request suggests some of your other scatterplots differ qualitatively from the one shown in the question.  Whether and how to adjust this multiplier comes down to their characteristics.  Nevertheless, there are automatic ways to adjust the multiplier dynamically, such as IRLS (aka IWLS). It often works well. If you implemented that with a spline you could fit the nonlinear shape of the main points while obtaining the automatic identification of outlying residuals.

Comment: BTW, it appears you have three accounts.  If you would merge them, you could combine your reputation and enhance your ability to interact with this site.  Please visit http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts.